# How exactly is the stack frame handled by the C language?

Tags: c

I was studying pointers and I came across the definition of stack frame. If i understood correctly when the address of the caller gets pushed in the stack, the local variables of the callee will be given an area of memory at the end of the stack called the stack frame.

To prove this i wrote this simple C program, the thing I was trying to do is to demonstrate the statement made before by accessing the local variables of a caller function by manipulating the addresses in the callee.

The thing that I don't understand is why I have to add TWO times `sizeof(int)` instead of just one time, given that based on the definition of stack frame variables gets allocated in a reverse order while we nest our functions since the end of the stack is being used, and given that the two functions that I wrote are both without parameters, I should be able to access the caller variable `x` by just adding ONE time the `sizeof(int)`, but I get the desired result only when I add to the base address `2*sizeof(int)`. Could you explain me why? Where am I getting stuck?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Func();
void Garbage();

int main()
{
    Func();
    return 0;
}

void Func()
{
    int x = 5;

    printf("Address of x: %p\n", &x);
    printf("Value of x: %d\n", x);
    
    Garbage();

    return;
}

void Garbage()
{
    int x; 

    printf("Address of x: %p\n", &x);
    printf("Value of x: %d\n", *(&x+2*(sizeof(int)));
    
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of x: 0x7ffc65629524
Value of x: 5
Address of x: 0x7ffc65629504 // Instead of 0x7ffc65629514
Value of x: 5
```

From my understanding I should be able to access `x` value in `Func()` scope by adding `sizeof(int)` just one time. But as you can see from the output the addresses of the two values are divided by one byte. Why? Is there a sort of guard that is being but between scopes of different nested functions?

Comment: The C Standard makes no mention of any stack; it's a matter for the OS and the particular implementation. The stack frame needed isn't just the size of the variables it has to carry, but has alignment considerations.

Comment: There are two errors I see in the code: a missing parenthesis, and the lack of initilisation of `int x`; in function `Garbage`. If I initialise this to `int x = 42;` the code code still outputs garbage: neither `5` nor `42`.

Comment: My compilation shows the two addresses differ by `64`.

Comment: try and checkout the compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/ this may give you some more info and is fun to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing that I don't understand is why I have to add TWO times sizeof(int) instead of just one time, given that based on the definition of stack frame variables gets allocated in a reverse order while we nest our functions since the end of the stack is being used, and given that the two functions that I wrote are both without parameters, I should be able to access the caller variable x by just adding ONE time the sizeof(int), but I get the desired result only when I add to the base address 2*sizeof(int).

This depends on how the processor stores the data on the stack.  Here, several approaches are used, and in many architectures (but specially in 64bit, where integers and pointers are different size ---32 vs. 64bit---) the amount of data made in one PUSH instruction, is different or the same, depending on how the compiler has available different sizes PUSH instructions or not.

This translates in that when you push a `char` data to the stack (one byte) a full integer (can be 32 or 64 bits, depending of the push instruction used to  do) is effectively pushed, and this integer can be established to be a 32 bit or 64 bit by the ABI (the abstract binary inteface between functions, that makes functions compiled from different compilers interoperable)  This can result in the problem you are experimenting, so I suggest you to consult the ABI implemented by your compiler, as binaries compiled by different compilers must agree on a common ABI to make your program never crash.

There are also calling conventions that use registers to pass function parameters (in that case a full register is used, independent of the data size) or anything.  The compiler also has to reserve space for local variables (the return addresss normally is between local parameters and local variables, as the local parameters get initialized from the calling code ---probably executed from a different compilation unit---, and local variables space is normally initialized by offsetting the stack pointer an amount ---that sometimes has alignment issues too)  Only after all of this is done, the function code is being executed.

C also has a characteristic that enforces the calling code to place the parameters in place, and call the foreign routine, and so, is responsible to do the cleaining of the used space after the function call.  Other languages that have a strict function specification (like pascal or java) allow the cleaning of parameters to be done in the call, but this enforces to always have the calling conventions known by the called routine compilation and by the calling routine.  C permits you to call a routine with different parameter types than the ones the function was written (this is a legacy from old C compilers, but has still to be respected) in code like this:

```
int f();

...
    x = f("Hello, world %d times\n", n);
```

and thing about the mess of having to put two parameters on the stack (let's say that we push all parameters on the stack) and what should do the routine if the parameter cleaning code was included in the internals of `f()`?

Answer (score -2):

In your code, when you access the local variable x of the caller function from the Garbage function, you are trying to calculate the address of x by adding an offset to the base address of the local variable in the Garbage function's stack frame.

In the Garbage function, you have declared a local variable x, and you want to access the caller function's variable x. To do that, you are adding an offset to the address of x in the Garbage function. However, the offset you are adding is not correct, and that's why you are not getting the expected result.

The correct offset to add depends on the size of the stack frame of the caller function. In your case, the stack frame of the caller function Func consists of just one local variable x. Each int typically occupies 4 bytes of memory, so you need to add an offset of sizeof(int) to access the variable x of the caller function.

Here's the corrected code for the Garbage function:`

```
void Garbage()
```

{
int x;

```
printf("Address of x: %p\n", &x);
printf("Value of x: %d\n", *((int*)((char*)&x + sizeof(int))));

return;
```

}

> n this code, &x gives you the address of the local variable x in the Garbage function. By casting it to a char*, you can treat it as a pointer to a character (1 byte in size). Then, by adding sizeof(int) to this address, you are effectively adding an offset of sizeof(int) bytes. Finally, you cast the result back to an int* to access the value stored at that memory location.

`

Comment: Even when I initialise `int x = 42;` in function `Garbage()` your solution does not output either `5` or `42`. You can't guess the size of the stack frame.

Comment: The content in this post seems to be AI generated. Please read Stack Overflow's guidelines regarding the same [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).